# PowerMock mock external library

Tags: java, mocking, mockito, testng, powermock

Really short question: How can I mock **response.getContentType()** ?
(Using PowerMock + TestNG)

- I'm not calling any new() methods.
- I'm trying to mock class, that is result of method execution of some other class.

**The class under test:**

```
class ClassToBeMocked {

    public String getJsonPage(String jsonUrl) throws IOException {
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);

        final Page page = webClient.getPage(jsonUrl);
        final WebResponse response = page.getWebResponse();
        final String cType = response.getContentType();

        if (cType.equals("application/json") || cType.equals("application/hal+json")) {
            return response.getContentAsString();
        }

        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unexpected response type " + response.getContentType());
    }
}
```

**Test itself**

```
@PrepareForTest( { WebResponse.class, ClassToBeMocked.class})
@PowerMockIgnore("javax.net.ssl.*")
public class UrlPullerTest extends PowerMockTestCase {

    @Test
    public void testGetPage() throws Exception {
        WebResponse mockwebResposne = PowerMockito.mock(WebResponse.class);
        PowerMockito.when(mockwebResposne.getContentType()).thenReturn("wrongType");

        ClassToBeMocked classToBeMocked = new ClassToBeMocked();
        classToBeMocked.getJsonPage("http://google.com");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't. Your problem is that you created **hard to test** code, by putting that **new** WebClient call into your source code. That leads to direct coupling of implementations.

You should use **dependency injection** instead (for example to inject a **factory** that creates WebClient objects for you). Doing so, you can do all your work with power-less frameworks such as EasyMock or Mokito.

Hint: far too often, the usage of PowerMock is an indication, that your design could be improved. No idea what I am talking about? Then watch these [videos](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLD0011D00849E1B79). Each one worth each minute!